# discord.py | discord.VoiceClient.play | getting an error trying to play an mp3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    if '!mvp' in message.content and message.author != client.user:
        print('MVP spotted.')
        await discord.VoiceClient.play(self,source='audio/quotes/CypherLastKillMVP.mp3')
```

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Barusu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Barusu\Desktop\discordBot\main.py", line 90, in on_message
await discord.VoiceClient.play(self,source='audio/quotes/CypherLastKillMVP.mp3')
File "C:\Users\Barusu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 554, in play
if not self.is_connected():
AttributeError: 'MyClient' object has no attribute 'is_connected'

Answer (score 0):

```
if '!mvp' in message.content and message.author != client.user:
   voice_client = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=message.guild)
   voice_client.play(*args)
```

If the bot is not connected to any voice channel, voice_client will be `None`.

Comment: I just started using discord.py and so far haven't used ctx at all. It's says it's an unresolved reference and I get this error when trying to use the command.

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
AttributeError: 'MyClient' object has no attribute 'bot'

Comment: @KomiKage, I have edited the answer. It is better to learn [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html) than using the on_message event.